# Weechat: Disable nick highlight in server buffers

Tags: weechat

Due to my nick being contained in some of the status messages that float around in server buffers, I will often get unwanted message notifications. Does weechat have a system to ignore highlights on a per-buffer basis, or perhaps specifically for status/server buffers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this with this:

```
/set irc.look.highlight_server ""
```

Comment: That took a while to get answered heh. Thanks a lot!